# iOS Shopify SDK compiler error: Value of type 'Array<PayCardBrand>' has no member 'compactMap'

Tags: ios, swift, shopify

I am working on a shopify project with latest version of SDK(3.1.5, GraphQL based) used. As integrate it with my project, when I run the project it throws me a compiler error:

> Value of type 'Array' has no member 'compactMap'

I searched for this error for getting a solution but can't. I also tried to make some modifications in that place but it makes more troubles.

Here is a screenshot

[image]

Comment: which Xcode version are you use?

Comment: use Xcode which support swift 4.1 or later

Comment: I am using Xcode 9.2...Ok I will

Comment: required  Xcode 9.3